# Setting up a static IP in AWS Security Group while using Cloudflare

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudflare

I want to set up a security group that will only allow my static IP to hit an EC2 server, but because I use Cloudflare and it uses some IP/reverse proxy magic, the AWS security group only sees the Cloudflare IP and not my actual static IP. I looked all over and can't find any answer to how to do this. Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with security group settings.

Caching proxies like Cloudflare create a separate connection to the origin server, using one of their IP addresses.

You'd need to use those addresses in your security group, and maintain the rules if Cloudflare changes the list.  But, the list is public.

https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/

Next, you need to configure your web server to deny requests when the `CF-Connecting-IP` HTTP header doesn't contain your IP address.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-Cloudflare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-

You have to do both, because if you don't restrict traffic to the Cloudflare IP address ranges with your security group, then traffic from elsewhere (not via Cloudflare) could forge the header containing the IP address.

Having done those two things, you have almost accomplished your objective, but not quite... because Cloudflare caches responses.

So, the next problem is, you also need to disable caching at Cloudflare, because once you fetch a page, it may be in the Cloudflare cache, where someone else might access it.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-PageRules-

Really, for a case where you need to restrict access to a single IP (or a small set), it doesn't usually make a lot of sense to send the traffic through Cloudflare.

Comment: If we setup proper security group, why do we need to configure our web server to check for CF-Connecting-IP header? Won't security group take care of filtering non-cf traffic?

Comment: @geek_guy yes, the security group will block non-Cloudflare traffic, but the question here involved allowing only a certain viewer IP address to access the site.  The security group sees the Cloudflare IP, so the application needs to inspect each request to see which IP address Cloudflare reports that it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a lambda function that parse the [IP file](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/) from Cloudflare and update your security groups dynamically. [AWSlabs on github](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudfront-samples/tree/master/update_security_groups_lambda) has an example lambda function that does it for CloudFront. Two problems you'll run into are that you'll have to schedule to lambda function to run since you can't subscribe to a queue like in the example and possible running out security group rules, [50 is the limit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_Limits.html#vpc-limits-security-groups).